# How do I fix a mismatch between processor Architectures?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, compiler-warnings, configurationmanager

I have a number of projects that I have combined in my project.  The error message I get is this:

There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference "Interop.Domino, Version=1.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=x86", "x86". This mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project through the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures between your project and references, or take a dependency on references with a processor architecture that matches the targeted processor architecture of your project.

I have found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23464802/answered-in-comments-mismatch-between-processor-architecture-of-the-project-an) which gives some interesting information.

However when I open up the Configuration Manager, everything looks fine:

[image: Configuration manager showing Any CPU selected]

Any idea of what I can do to get rid of this compiler message?

Comment: Basically... if one of DLLs you use has x86 architecture, rest of it should also. x64 assembly will not run on x86 machine, opposite is OK.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To me this looks like the Interop.Domino Library you're referencing is specifically for 32bit (x86) programs. You can either try to find a 64 bit version of the library and reference that instead or change the compile type of your programs.

You can do this by opening the properties page for each of your projects and setting the Platform target to x86.

You might like to create an X86 Configuration in Configuration manager first, partly to test it out on and partly so it has the right name when you look at it later.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

It is complaining about a reference for one of your projects.  Specifically, Interop.Domino.  I'm assuming that's something to do with Domino, which likely means you have no control over it.

There's very little chance that it will be an issue, if you are in a Windows environment on Intel or AMD processors.

If you don't need the ability for this application to address more than ~2GB of memory, then go ahead and compile the project referencing it in x86 mode as well, if you're worried about the warning.